# Verificar se arquivo existe através da URL com .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, url-amigável

Tenho a seguinte situação, preciso verificar se um determinado arquivo existe, baseado na URL que estou tentando acessar, caso ele exista exibe normalmente, do contrário redireciona para uma pagina de erro.

Por exemplo:

Possuo o seguinte arquivo `/paginas/contato.php` , ao chamar acessar a URL **meusite.com/contato** o .htaccess verificaria se o arquivo existe e o carregaria, caso contrario redirecionaria para uma pagina de erro.

Como deveria ficar a estrutura do .htaccess para atender essa necessidade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução para o meu problema e vou compartilhar aqui.

`RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/temas/paginas/$1\.php -f [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /temas/paginas/$1\.php [L]`

No meu caso eu precisava verificar se um determinado arquivo existia dentro da subpasta **/temas/paginas** do servidor e exibi-lo de acordo com a url acessada.

Por exemplo se eu acessar a URL **meusite.com.br/contato** , ele ira verificar se o arquivo **/temas/paginas/contato.php** existe, e vai carrega-lo.